# Are these regular Perl subroutine calls?

Tags: perl, oop, methods

I'm still trying to get a hang of Perl's OOP features. I'm confused about something, if I have a subroutine call like:

```
My::Package::sub_name($param1,$param2)
```

will this get "My::Package" sent as the first parameter? I'd tend to say no, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you just try it?

Spoiler alert:

No, the first parameter will not be the package name.

However, when you do:

```
My::Package->sub_name( $param1, $param2 )
```

you will get the package/class name as the first parameter.

Comment: I had tried something like that, but I was thinking whether or not it was a general rule.

Answer (score 10):

(As Manni says) It's the [`->` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html#Introducing-the-method-invocation-arrow) that unshifts the invocant to `@_` (where the invocant is either a blessed object, or a bare class name). `::` in the function name is just used for namespace disambiguation and does not change `@_`.

Posted as an answer as per Geo's suggestion, although I don't want to be a rep whore :)

It's described more in the docs: [perldoc perlboot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlboot.html#The-extra-parameter-of-method-invocation), [perldoc perltoot](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltoot.html).

Comment: Hey I hit 3k, I felt like slowing down for a bit.. :)

Comment: Hmm. I was a bit surprised to be the only one answering that. However, I really expected a lengthy diatribe about indirect object notation upon revisiting this question.